# How to type cast in Typescript? Is it an 'as?' operator?

Tags: typescript

This line is not accepted:

```
const oid: string | undefined = keyPath[0]
```

bacause, `keyPath` array can have number or string elements.

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I tried also this:

```
const oid?: string = keyPath[0]
```

In Swift I could use an `as?` operator. Does it exist in Typescript. It would try to cast to i.e. string, if not possible then it return an undefined. What about Typescript. Does it exist similar operator?

Comment: [Please do some research](https://www.w3schools.com/typescript/typescript_casting.php) before posting on stackoverflow. If you run into any problems or errors, you csn ask a question (or edit this one).

Answer (score 2):

There is an `as` operator in typescript. However, this does not cast the value at runtime like you may expect. It just tells the typescript compiler that this can be treated as string. The code below will compile, but the value of `bar` is still a `number`:

```
const foo: number = 1;
const bar: string = foo as string;
console.log(bar); // This will output the number 1 (not the string '1')
```

If you really want to check the type at runtime, you can use the `typeof` operator like this:

```
const key: string | number = keyPath[0]
const oid: string | undefined = typeof key === 'string' ? key : undefined;
```

This code does really perform a runtime check so you can be sure `keyPath[0]` is actually a string. The typescript compiler does also understand this expression and will narrow the type correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found:

```
const oid: string | undefined = keyPath ? (keyPath[0] as string) : undefined
```

Comment: It becomes `const oid = keyPath ? keyPath[0] : undefined` in JS, which is probably not what you want. (it will still allow oid to become numeric during runtime)

Comment: no, it is ok, as it is a known info, inplicit info, first position has always string

Comment: If so, then it may be possible to use a more specific type for `keyPath`, for example `let keyPath: [string, ... (string|number)[] ]` which will tell the compiler that the first position is always string. The type of `keyPath[0]` will be inferred automatically as string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).